# Can the last few boards of hardwood near a wall be glued if there is not alot of space for nailing

Tags: hardwood-floor

So you get near the wall and cannot use the floor nailer or brad nailer to get a nail in through the tongue at an angle.  I have seen advice to glue a board like this down vs trying to drill a guide hole and hand nail.  For the glue types, some just fill the groove and attach the next board, some do this and glue to the floor.  It doesn't seem to make sense to have a board glued to the subfloor (wood) when the rest are nailed (to allow it to move/expand).  Did a quick check of other answers and it seems that nailing is the way to go, though it is more work.  Make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Either glue it to the adjacent board or use regular trim nails at the edge where they'll be covered by base trim.

Answer (score 3):

we just do the last few runs with 2in brad nails.  you can easily fill and hide the heads with lacquer sticks.  we put woodglue under every square foot of hardwood flooring we lay.  its not even a point of debate.  the wood will expand and contract with glue or without it.  its just a question of how soon you want the floor to squeak and cup.  wood glue prevents that almost entirely.

Comment: Do you glue it down to tar paper?

Comment: Tar paper? what are you talking about?  if you put tar paper inside your house, you will be breathing VOC's for years.  if you mean flooring paper, then no - you don't glue to  paper.  the paper is there merely as a lubricating  layer to help the wood slip and not squeak as it expands and contracts.   you just glue right down to the subfloor

Answer (score -1):

Glue definitely! But a mechanical fastener is needed, since glue's no good once its grip breaks & it will. Nails are okay, but they're the sole reason for squeaks. Go with Finish or Trim Screws instead of nails for a far superior job. And yes, I mean for the whole floor. Screws nail nails, Nails will screw you.